# Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4:SIGILL)

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm encountering an issue while running TensorFlow on PyCharm Community within my Ubuntu 22.4 LTS environment using VirtualBox. Specifically, when attempting to execute the code import tensorflow as tf in PyCharm with Python version 3.10 and TensorFlow version 2.16.1, I encounter the following error: (Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4:SIGILL)).

Here are the system details of my host PC.

### System Information

```
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 22631) (22621.ni_release.220506-1250)
Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: ASUS
System Model: System Product Name
BIOS: 0703 (type: UEFI)
Processor: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700K (24 CPUs), ~3.4GHz
Memory: 65536MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 65278MB RAM
Page File: 21266MB used, 53738MB available
DirectX Version: DirectX 12
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
DirectX Database Version: 1.5.0
```

I would like the following code to run successfully:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance from the Stack Overflow community in resolving this matter. Thank you.